# Transaction migration for EJB in JBoss/WildFly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

We have designed an Enteprise application on WildFly 8.2 which uses as back-end EJBs for performing transactions (by persisting Entities).
Is it possible to configure an EJB so that if a failure happens when a transaction is running, the transactional context moves to another node in the cluster ? (Meaning that the backup node will be able to continue the transaction started on the node that crashed) 
Thanks

Comment: I do not really understand your question. May I ask for the original problem?

Comment: I'd need to know what happens if a failure happens during an XA Transaction ? is it possible to continue the transaction on the backup node somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism that provides this behaviour.

You would need to catch the failure and retry the entire transaction.